# MMQgis Plugin error in Qgis

Tags: qgis-plugins, error, road

I am using Qgis 1.9 . I have downloaded a plugin "mm  qgis", however When I run this plugin I am getting following error:

An error has occured while executing Python code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\15491/.qgis2/python/plugins\mmqgis\mmqgis_dialogs.py", line 525, in run
    message = mmqgis_geometry_convert(self.iface, layername, newtype, splitnodes, savename, 1)
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\15491/.qgis2/python/plugins\mmqgis\mmqgis_library.py", line 1154, in mmqgis_geometry_convert
    layer.dataProvider().select(layer.dataProvider().attributeIndexes())
AttributeError: 'QgsVectorDataProvider' object has no attribute 'select'

Python version:
2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

QGIS version:
1.9.0-Master Master, 1a723b4

Python path: ['C:\Documents and Settings\15491/.qgis2/python/plugins\sextante_taudem', 'C:\Documents and Settings\15491/.qgis2/python/plugins\sextante_animove', 'C:\Documents and Settings\15491/.qgis2/python/plugins\sextantelwgeomprovider', 'C:\Documents and Settings\15491/.qgis2/python/plugins\sextanteexampleprovider', 'C:\Documents and Settings\15491/.qgis2/python/plugins\sextante', 'C:\Documents and Settings\15491/.qgis2/python/plugins\permaclim', 'C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-dev/./python', 'C:\Documents and Settings\15491/.qgis2/python', 'C:\Documents and Settings\15491/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-dev/./python/plugins', 'C:\OSGeo4W\bin\python27.zip', 'C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\DLLs', 'C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib', 'C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win', 'C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk', 'C:\OSGeo4W\bin', 'C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27', 'C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages', 'C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL', 'C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32', 'C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 'C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin', 'C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\Documents and Settings\15491\.qgis2\python\plugins\mmqgis/forms', 'C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-dev\python\plugins\fTools\tools', 'C:\Documents and Settings\15491\.qgis2\python\plugins\pdokbaggeocoder/forms']
 what is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That version of QGIS is very old.  The version of the plugin you have wasn't migrated to the new API.

1. Download the latest QGIS version
2. Install plugins via the plugin manger

Comment: can u suggest me the correct website to download the latest version?

Comment: the plugin is maintained here - http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/mmqgis/